# Automatic title to file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, title

When a new class is generated in eclipse a title which may looks like this is generated:

```
/*
 * $Id $
 *
 * $Date$
 * $Revision$
 * $Author$
 *
 * Copyright YourCompany${year}, All Rights Reserved.
 */
```

Do yo know if there is a way to change this title for somethink custom and if there is a way to apply it automaticaly to all te classes which already exists?

cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this in code templates (Preferences->Java->Code Style->Code Templates), but no, you can't apply it to all classes which already exist.

The particular comment that you're looking for is (probably) in Comments->Files.

Answer (score 1):

to do so:

1- open eclipse.ini file in the eclipse directory.

2- add the following line after -vmargs line

-Duser.name=your name

References:

http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg07148.html